# jquery start a series of simulated clicks, stop when required

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a link that a user can click when they want to 'start' the guided tour. What it does is it simulates a bunch of clicks using setTimeouts -- almost like a slideshow (its a one page website).

However, when a user clicks one of the manual navigation links, I want this automatic guided tour to STOP. Any suggestions?

/EDIT: This is how I need this to work...

I need to `.click()` `#nav_a` immediately then after 5 seconds `.click()` `#nav_b` and so on (all the way to `#nav_e`.

When a user clickers `#stop` it will stop the automatic `.click()` process

When a user clicks `#start` again it will start all over from `#nav_a`

Comment: use `clearTimeout` / `clearInterval`.

Comment: I prefer setTimeout / clearTimeout so the timeout spawns another timeout as you can pass context of one timeout spawning another very easily and this leads to more responsible programming when you are explicit.

Comment: Since I'm spawning new setTimeouts how will I be able to set which one to clear when 'stop' is clicked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made the slide show circular but you can have it stop at the end if you like. The basic logic is when the slide is clicked, it cancels the automatic playing.

```
<div class="slides">
  <div class="slide">[ content ]</div>
  <div class="slide">[ content ]</div>
  <div class="slide">[ content ]</div>
</div>
<script>
var stopSlideshow = false,
slideTimeout = null,
slideTime = 5000, // 5 seconds
doSlide = function($slide) {
   $('.slide').not($slide).hide(); // hide all but current slide
   $slide.show(); // show current slide
   $slide = ($slide.next().length) ? $slide.next() : $('.slide:first');
   if (!stopSlideshow) { // automatically keeps going if slide show not stopped
       slideTimeout = window.setTimeout(function(){doSlide($slide);}, slideTime);
   }
};
$('.slide').bind('click',function(ev){
   stopSlideshow = true; // set flag
   window.clearTimeout(slideTimeout); // stop timeout
   $('.slide').unbind(); // cancel slide click
});
doSlide($('.slide:first')); // start wizard
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add an mask div which is transparent, when user click, you can catch the event and stop `setTimeout`.